# what is the use of "#@" in c language?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The **`#`** symbol is used at the start of preprocessor directives (`#ifdef`, `#define` etc). `#` is also used as the stringification operator.

**`##`** is the token pasting operator.

Then in an online quiz I saw this:

```
#define MAKECHAR(operand) #@operand
```

What operator is **`#@`** and what is it used for?

Comment: What makes you think this has a special meaning?

Comment: There exists nothing like `#@` in standard C.

Comment: I haven't ever heard that `@` has any meaning in C. I would assume it's a proprietary extension. If so, it should be documented in the doc. of the resp. C compiler.

Comment: #define MAKECHAR(operand) #@operand , i was found this line in a C Quiz.

Comment: Sometimes @ is used in comments to highlight text that is to be handled by other tools like Doxygen.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yepp. (I guess it was adopted from JavaDoc.) but then it may be used in comments exclusively and is "transparent" for the C compiler.

Comment: @Scheff correct. I didn't claim anything different. :)

Comment: _i was found this line in a C Quiz_ may be, an underhanded attempt to test you, or just a formatting error of the Web site author... ;-)

Comment: It's not standard C, but Microsoft preprocessors have a ["charizing" operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91tt6dfs.aspx), `#@` in analogy to the (standard) stringizing operator `#`.

Comment: @bhura112 I've edited your question quite substantially - much better now ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Antti Haapala

Comment: FYI, since nobody has mentioned it yet, `@` isn't even in the C++ "basic source character set".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an analogy to the stringify marker `#` but for characters, but it is not standardized. For example, clang/llvm does not support it.

To show the analogy:

```
#define MESSAGE(x) printf("%s: %d\n", #x, x)

int main(){
    int i = 5;
    MESSAGE(i); // expands to printf("%s: %d\n", "i", x)
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
i: 5
```

With a compiler supporting `#@`, you could write:

```
#define MESSAGE(x) printf("%c: %d\n", #@x, x)

int main(){
    int i = 5;
    MESSAGE(i);  // expands to printf("%c: %d\n", 'i', x)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only nice thing about this charizing operator seems to be that it is an integer constant expression - otherwise it is rather useless and could be circumvented easily with stringification and dereferencing.